# Easy way to set irb to alias requires to home directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irb

Is there an easy way to set IRB to alias the home directory to the correct path? ie. if I do a `require('~')` in an irb terminal it will require my home directory at the correct path?

Comment: Do you want a different HOME env? This can be accomplished during the launch by overloading the BASH HOME

Comment: "~" needs expansion. If you want to avoid that, you can set irb to move the current directory to the home on boot.

Comment: Right I was curious on how to automate the expansion. Is there a config for irb you can set or do I have to manually do it?